# Why did Rachel weep for her children?

Tags: matthew, prophecy

We all know the famous, dark side of Christmas:

> When Herod realized that he had been outwitted by the Magi, he was furious, and he gave orders to kill all the boys in Bethlehem and its vicinity who were two years old and under, in accordance with the time he had learned from the Magi. Then what was said through the prophet Jeremiah was fulfilled: “A voice is heard in Ramah, weeping and great mourning, Rachel weeping for her children and refusing to be comforted, because they are no more.”     (Matthew 2:16-18 NIV)

However, when I read this today I could not understand one thing. Why does Rachel weep for Bethlehem? Isn't Bethlehem part of Judah? Why does Rachel mourn for Leah's children?

Comment: Hello and welcome. I'm a little puzzled by the way this is framed ("Why does Rachel...?"). Are you wondering about this from the perspective of Matthew or Jeremiah? I'm having a hard time getting my head around thinking about it from the perspective of *Rachel*, which seems to be requested.  ?

Comment: Not sure if this is connected,  but there is debate whether Rachel died and was buried near Bethlehem in Judah, Gen 35:19, or just on the road on the way to Ephrath and is buried in Benjamin land near Ramah, 1 Samuel 10:2.

Comment: @Susan To be honest, I didn't put much thought into it; it was just a question that popped into my head as I read Matthew. But is there a difference in the perspective of Matthew and Jeremiah concerning Rachel? If so, I would like to hear about both of the perspectives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A close examination of scripture reveals Rachael's death and burial location as falling short of reaching Ephrath. Jacob made mention of this:

> Gen 48:7  As for me, when I came from Paddan, Rachel died beside me in
>   the land of Canaan on the way, when there was **still some distance to
>   come to Ephrath**, and I buried her there on the way to Ephrath (also
>   called Bethlehem).” (WEB)

A more precise location of Rachael's burial grounds is found in 1 Sam 10:2. Samuel told young Saul (after his anointing) he would meet men near Rachael's tomb, *on the border of Benjamin at Zelzah*: Zelah being a few miles southwest of Jerusalem.

> 1Sa 10:2  When you have departed from me today, **then you will find
>   two men by Rachel’s tomb, on the border of Benjamin at Zelzah**. They
>   will tell you, ‘The donkeys which you went to look for have been
>   found; and behold, your father has stopped caring about the donkeys,
>   and is anxious for you, saying, “What shall I do for my son".

**Why did Jeremiah ascribe weeping to Rachael?**

First, we must go back to the context of Gen 35:16-19. Here we find Rachael in the hard labor that would lead to her death. There are two interesting events that transpire during this time. One, Rachael was comforted by her handmaiden with these words:
 *“Don’t be afraid, for now you will have another son.”* Gen 35:17.

Two, Rachel names her son Benomi, which means "son of my pain/sorrow".

For Rachael the source of her physical pain and her hope rested in giving birth to a child. As with other biblical women, the hope of bearing children was linked to the birth of the savior (Gen 3:15).

The prophet Jeremiah figuratively describes a weeping Rachael when the residents of Judah (which contained a large element of tribal Benjamin) are gathered at Ramah by the Babylonian army and deported to Babylon.

But notice the words of consolation that are given to the weeping Rachael in Jer 31.

> Jer 31:16  Yahweh says: “Refrain your voice from weeping, and your
>   eyes from tears; for your work will be rewarded,” says Yahweh. “**They
>   will come again from the land of the enemy".**

It's from Yahweh. God assures Rachael that the deported children will return to the land. The evil Nebuchadnezzar seemingly ended the *Promise* of Israel, but God promises a return of His nation.

Matthew, under the inspiration of God, picked up on Rachael's weeping theme to describe *her sorrow* of the killing of the innocents in Matt 2:18 (arguably some of her physical descendants). Here again, her offspring being the subject of sorrow and promise. Although no consolation is given Rachael in this passage as previously done, Matthew subsequently chronicled the exiled Jesus and return from Egypt to prove how the life of young Jesus fulfilled key historical aspects of national Israel's history. In other words, although there was sorrow and pain throughout Judea, true consolation had arrived via the birth of the Savior.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to keep in mind that a lot of the Bible's passages and scriptures is Literary Art which would involve poety and literary devices (i.e., hyperbole, figure-of-speech, metaphor, simile, etc. ) and therefore, should **Not be taken too literarily**.

Therefore, in regard to using "Rachel" in the aforementioned scripture that the OP mentions, it might just generally be symbolism for Israel's matriarchs or something representing the mothers of the Israelite children who must have been emotionally saddened by the atrocity associated with the killing of so many children.

Answer (score 0):

It is figurative. However it is not correct that Rachel wept for her sister Leah's children i.e. descendants in this context. Bethlehem was in Judah and Judah was made up of two tribes, being Judah and Benjamin. Benjamin was the second son of Rachel who she had before dying from childbirth complications.

After David's sin of adultery with Bathsheba, wife of Uriah the Hitite, God told him the kingdom would be taken from him, but because of early promise was left with two tribes in the reign of Rehoboam his grandson. The ten tribes are given to Jeroboam and called Israel. Though the ruling families keep changing in Israel, those of the two tribes in the southern kingdom, called Judah, remain within David's family and through which Jesus the Messiah is born.

Two tribes from the older brother of Benjamin, Joseph i.e. Manessah and Ephraim are however within the northern kingdom of Israel

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).